# Fourier transformation on $\{T_\theta\}$ is surjective

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

Let $S$ Schwartz space on $\mathbb{R}^2$. For $f\in S$, let $T(f):=\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} f(0,y)dy$ and $T_{\theta} (f):=T(f(x \cos{\theta} -y \sin{\theta}, x\sin{\theta} +y\cos{\theta}))$ and we note $F$ Fourier transformation.
Then $F(\{T_\theta\}_{\theta \in \mathbb{R}})=\{T_\theta\}_{\theta \in \mathbb{R}}$.

I proved $T_{\theta} \in S'$ by calculation, so I want to prove  $F:\{T_\theta\} \to \{T_\theta\}$ is surjective. But I can't prove.

Comment: @CalvinKhor. Why would $T_\theta$ be a constant?

Comment: @CalvinKhor. $T = \delta \otimes 1 \in \mathcal D'(\mathbb R^2)$ and $\langle T_\theta, f \rangle = \langle T, f_\theta \rangle$

Comment: James, if $F(\{T_\theta\}_{\theta \in \mathbb{R}})=\{T_\theta\}_{\theta \in \mathbb{R}}$ then $F(T_\theta) = T_\phi$ for some $\phi$, isn't it? Have you found any relationship between $\theta$ and $\phi$?

Comment: @md2perpe oh I misinterpreted the question. Many thanks

Comment: No, I haven't. In my calculation, double integrals don't vanish…

Comment: What is your exact definition of Fourier transform on $S$?

Comment: for  $f\in S$, $Ff(a,b):=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y) e^{-2\pi i(xa+yb)}dxdy$

Comment: So $F(\delta) = 1$ and $F(1) = \delta$?

Comment: Try to show these two identities:
$$F(T)(f) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x, 0) \, dx \, dy = T_{\pi/2}(f)$$

Comment: How's it going?